# Function returns before completing her job

Tags: javascript, promise, return

I've written this function, and it returns the values, before doing her job. So the return is allways `undefined`. How can I get the right results?

The code:

```js
async function isReachable(hostname, port) {
  net
    .connect(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(true);
      return true;
    })
    .on('error', () => {
      console.log(false);
      return false;
    });
}
```

The log:

```sh
Promise { undefined }
true
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You may try to add 'await' before 'net'.

Comment: Allready tried. Returns:
Promise { <pending> }
true

Comment: With this: `async function fn() {
  await console.log(sr.isReachable("mc.hypixel.net", 25565));
}` its the same issue.

Comment: not exactly, you should add 'return' before 'await' !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If net.connect() doesn't return a Promise you will need to wrap the function implementation in a Promise and use the resolve() callback to return true/false within the .connect() and .on() callback functions.

```
function isReachable(hostname, port) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      net
        .connect(port, hostname, () => {
          resolve(true);
        })
        .on('error', () => {
          resolve(false);
        });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: using `async` automatically turns the return to a `Promise` - you can simply use `return await net.connect...` to achieve the same thing, though for both cases, you'll need to `await` `isReachable()` as well

Comment: Why is it returning `Promise { <pending> }`?

Comment: Ok thank you, my misstake, its working... :)

Comment: I agree with @divillysausages, async (and await) will return a promise, so no need to create a promise inside a promise !

Comment: Jest tells me now, that there are open hanles, how can I fix this?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA what if net.connect(port, hostname, callbackFn) doesn't return a promise but instead requires a callbackFn which it calls once complete?

Comment: @AdrianZielonka, if so, i.e. if net doesnt return promise, so no need to put async ! The best solution is to put 'await' across of 'async' !

Answer (score 1):

Change the start of your method to this:

```
async function isReachable(hostname, port) {
  return net
    .connect(
...
```

You're missing the `return`, and you're getting the default `undefined` return.

`isReachable` will then return a `Promise` that you can `await` for the result

Comment: Does this implementation assume net.connect(...) returns a promise?

Comment: `async` means that it'll return a `Promise` no matter what. E.g. `async function test() { return 5 }` returns a `Promise` that will resolve to `5`

Comment: @AdrianZielonka, it's not our job to assume that the net will return a promise or not. But, net returns a promise, in that case, your code is totally incoherent since you return a promise which returning another promise !

Answer (score 0):

If net returns a promise, the correct solution, for me, should contain 'async' accros of 'await'. Take a look at the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await):

> The advantage of an async function only becomes apparent when you combine it with the await keyword. await only works inside async functions within regular JavaScript code, however it can be used on its own with JavaScript modules.
>
> await can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the resulting value.

Something like this:

```
async function isReachable(hostname, port) {
  return netResults = await net
    .connect(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(true);
      return true;
    })
    .on('error', () => {
      console.log(false);
      return false;
    });
}
```